# ORA-01952: system privileges not granted to 'ROJIB

Tags: sql, database, oracle

why do i get ORA-01952: system privileges not granted to 'ROJIB' ?

create role :

```
SQL> create role security;

Role created.
```

and then create grant for role 'security' :

```
SQL> grant create table,create view to security;

Grant succeeded.
```

grant for user :

```
SQL> grant security to rojib;

Grant succeeded.
```

after in revoke, i get the error :

```
SQL> revoke create table from rojib;
revoke create table from rojib
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01952: system privileges not granted to 'ROJIB'
```

Comment: You have granted the privilege to the user through a role, while you are trying to revoke the privilege from the user rather than revoking it from the role.

Answer (score 3):

> why do i get ORA-01952: system privileges not granted to 'ROJIB' ?

That's because you granted a privilege to the **ROLE** `SECURITY`, so you need to **REVOKE** the privilege from the **ROLE** `SECURITY`, not the **USER**.

For example,

**Create a USER:**

```
SQL> CREATE USER TEST IDENTIFIED BY TEST;

User created.
```

**Create a ROLE:**

```
SQL> CREATE ROLE SECURITY;

Role created.
```

**Grant privileges to the ROLE:**

```
SQL> GRANT CREATE TABLE,CREATE VIEW TO SECURITY;

Grant succeeded.
```

**Grant ROLE to the USER:**

```
SQL> GRANT SECURITY TO TEST;

Grant succeeded.
```

**Revoke privilege from the ROLE:**

```
SQL> REVOKE CREATE TABLE FROM SECURITY;

Revoke succeeded.
```

**Revoke ROLE from the USER:**

```
SQL> REVOKE SECURITY FROM TEST;

Revoke succeeded.
```